# If object.value == this, then ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have 3 tables. Each one represents users with different roles. These are for Admins, basic users and ALL users. I want to add a filter onto my `ng-repeat`, or in my controller, to show only users with a role that matches what I want.  Here is my object:

```
  {
  "object": {
    "users": [
      {
        "uuid": "19c5808b-0dcf-4b62-9c09-6caac1a5",
        "fullname": "Brittani V",
        "email": "brit@test.com",
        "role": "root",
        "last_log_in": 1427806300,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "active": true
      },
      {
        "uuid": "b88415e9-a492-4206-83b4-5e7c42df",
        "fullname": "Eric S.",
        "email": "eric@test.com",
        "role": "root",
        "last_log_in": 1427817626,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "active": true
      },
      {
        "uuid": "25649ad3-0e72-4946-b5bf-3484dcd2",
        "fullname": "Joshua H.",
        "email": "josh@test.com",
        "role": "root",
        "last_log_in": 1427813063,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "active": true
      }
    ]
```

Here's my table with the category name of 'Administrator'

```
<tab heading="Administrators">

                <table class="table table-hover members-table middle-align">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <!-- <th></th> -->
                        <th>Name and Role</th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">E-MAIL</th>
                        <th>Last Login<th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="user in users **if user's role == root** ">
                        <!--    <td class="user-cb">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="cbr" name="members-list[]" value="1" checked />
                        </td>-->
                        <td class="user-name">
                            <a href="" class="name">{{user.fullname}}</a>
                            <span>{{user.role}}</span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                            <span class="email">{{user.email}}</span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="user-id">
                            {{user.last_log_in}}

                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <a href="" class="edit">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <a href="" class="delete">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>

                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </tab>
```

Comment: I've also tried this `<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter: user.role == 'root' ">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-if`, or `ng-hide`

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-if="user.role == 'root'">
```

Comment: ng-if is better is it will not be in the DOM.